# Create new extension for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to create custom extension and show on the side bar and which will be visible always when vs code is working?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike mentioned this is not possible yet. The corresponding feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43645). The API should be proposed with 2018 April release.